# Full disk encryption: What cipher do I have and does it have the NSA backdoor?

Tags: partitioning, encryption, security, lvm

I have installed Kubuntu 20.10. I have opted for LVM with full disk encryption.

1. I don't understand what cipher do I have. Do I have AES-256? The installation wizard DID NOT let me choose the cipher.
2. How can I be sure that the encryption algorithm does not have an NSA backdoor built into it?

Comment: RE: NSA Backdoor, that was done with *specific* companies to add the backdoor - that 'backdoor' that was referred to regularly isn't a 'generic backdoor' it was intentionally added by certain commercial solutions - I believe LUKS and its spec are public and don't have a backdoor (probably would've been identified by the public and sniped hard).  As for the ciphers, etc. the Wizard has defaults - but that question and such might be better referred to the mailing lists, rather than here, as the LUKS implementations aren't necessarily well known by the community-at-large with the Ubuntu defaults.

Comment: You can find out which cipher is used though by doing a `cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sdxx` on the encrypted device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`cryptsetup(8)`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/cryptsetup.8.html) to see what cipher is in use on your system. On my laptop, for example:

```
$ ls -l /dev/mapper
total 0
crw------- 1 root root 10, 236 Nov 12 20:22 control
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Nov 12 20:22 luks1 -> ../dm-0
$ sudo cryptsetup status luks1
/dev/mapper/luks1 is active and is in use.
  type:    LUKS2
  cipher:  aes-xts-plain64
  keysize: 256 bits
  key location: keyring
  device:  /dev/nvme0n1p4
  sector size:  512
  offset:  32768 sectors
  size:    1998277263 sectors
  mode:    read/write
  flags:   discards 
$
```

Discovering backdoors is a complicated topic that cannot be covered concisely. The source code for all components are available to review and rebuild and review the built versions, etc. This is probably best considered still an open problem in computer science.